# Where would a pure inductive or capacitive load be placed on a Smith chart, assuming the TL impedance is real?

Tags: smith-chart

I'm a new HAM operator, and just started learning about the amazing tool that is Smith charts; and it got me wondering what the edge case of a pure inductive or capacitive load would be? Since the normalized real part is 0, would they be plotted in the same spot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forgive me for my knowledge of transmission lines and microwave circuits is very minuscule.

Wikipedia has a very good image of how the Smith Chart is organized (for impedance):
[image]

Looking at the imaginary vs. real axis, you can basically determine real and imaginary components of the impedance. If you had to cut horizontal line across the middle of this circle in half, you would see that top half would be a more inductive load and the bottom half being a more capacitive load.

Henceforth, using the picture above, if the reflection coefficient, \$\Gamma=j\$, it would mean that the transmission has a purely inductive load. Otherwise if the reflection coefficient, \$\Gamma=-j\$, it would indicate a purely capacitive load.

I'm not sure what you mean by *"assuming the TL impedance is real"*. If the impedance was only real and *not* complex, it would mean your transmission line would be purely resistive with no indication of induction or capacitance.

Remember that your formula for impedance is:

\$z=r+jx\$,

where \$r\$ is your resistance, \$j\$ is your imaginary number \$\sqrt{-1}\$ and \$x\$ is your reactance which is your "resistance" of your capacitance or inductance, so to speak.

Comment: It's worth adding that inductors have positive reactance, so a pure inductive load will be on the outer edge of the top half of the chart. Capacitors have negative reactance, so a pure capacitive load will be on the outer edge of the bottom half of the chart. Since one is on the top half and the other is on the bottom half, they won't be in the same place.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, I only specified that the TL impedance was real because if it wasn't, then a pure inductive load wouldn't have a reflection coefficient of j, it would be something else with respect to the TL's

Comment: @ThePhoton Yes that's true. If someone didn't know about reactance of a circuit, I could see why that would be confusing. The polarity of reactance can indicate the amount of inductance and capacitance a circuit may have.

Comment: @ccolton, It would be more clear to say the reference impedance is real. For example you can characterize a 40 ohm line for use in a 50-ohm system, and even if your transmission line is lossy (like all real lines are) you normally characterize it relative to a purely real reference impedance, not to a complex reference impedance.

Comment: @ThePhoton I'm now a bit more confused. I totally agree with saying that the reference impedance is real, but what do you mean that "you can characterize a 40 ohm line for use in a 50-ohm system"? As in you're not characterizing a load with reference to a TL, just using a Smith chart for a different application?

Answer (score 3):

Impedances with a real component of zero are plotted along the circumference (outer edge) of the Smith chart. Inductive reactance above the horizontal mid-line, capacitive reactance below it.